# Java Array deleting confusion?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying to create a program that will remove a element from the array that the user wants, and to have the array deleting in a loop. The problem that I have is deleting the extra array elements after removing an element. I have been going at this for about 3 hours and got no where. Please help me. Thank you.

Here is what I mean:

```
The array list: 10 20 30 40 50

Which number should be removed for the list?
Number to delete: 20
10 30 40 50 
Try again? y/n

Which number should be removed for the list?
Number to delete: 30
10 40 **50 50**

Try again? y/n
```

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DeleteElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int del = 0;

        int intArray[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

        System.out.println("\n---- Part 3 of the Homework----");

        char yN;
        boolean yes = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
        }

        do {
            System.out.print("\nWhich number should be removed for the list? ");
            del = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Number to delete: " + del);

            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                if (intArray[i] == del) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        for (int b = i; b < intArray.length - 1; b++) {
                            intArray[b] = intArray[b + 1];
                            System.out.print(intArray[b] + " ");
                        }
                    }
                    if (i > 0 && i <= intArray[i]) {
                        for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                            System.out.print(intArray[c] + " ");
                        }
                        for (int a = i; a < intArray.length - 1; a++) {
                            intArray[a] = intArray[a + 1];
                            System.out.print(intArray[a] + " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nDelete again? y/n");
            input.nextLine();
            yN = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            if (yN == 'y') {
                yes = true;
            } else if (yN == 'n') {
                yes = false;
            }
        } while (yes != false);
    }
}
```

Comment: An array is a fixed size. You would probably be better off using a `List`.

Comment: Is it printing \*\*50 50\*\*? You don't have any * so it's a bit confusing. You are also making your method more complicated than it needs to be, but that's what learning is for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the code that prints the result: it always assumes that only one item has been "removed". Of course you cannot really remove items from an array - all you can do is pretending that the last `K` elements are not there, and not print them.

You need to keep the count to know when to stop - in other words, instead of

```
for (int a = i; a < intArray.length - 1; a++ )
```

you should write

```
for (int a = i; a < intArray.length - removedCount; a++ )
```

Start `removedCount` at zero, and increment it each time you remove an element.

Comment: Where would I initialize removeCount?

Comment: @Germblaster outside the `do` / `while` loop.

Comment: Ok, I have it like this: `for(int b = i; b < intArray.length - removeCount; b++){`                                  `removeCount++;`                `intArray[b] = intArray[b + 1];`
              `System.out.print(intArray[b] + " ");`

Comment: and i am not getting the 50(last element)to print out?

Comment: @Germblaster `removeCount` shouldn't be incremented in the `for` loop - it should be incremented right after the `if (intArray[i] == del) {...` statement. Unrelated note: `i > 0 && i <= intArray[i]` condition is highly suspicious.

Comment: `i > 0 && i <= intArray[i]`  is used to get elements between 0 and the index.  I dont know a better way to put it??

Comment: @Germblaster `i <= intArray[i]` compares an index to an element of the array at index `i`, e.g. 1 to 40, 3 to 40, etc. The thing is, you can replace both `if`s with the body of the second `if`. You do not need to check `i` for zero - if it happens to be zero, the first `for` loop (i.e the one `for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)`) will execute zero times, which is completely OK, because nobody is going to notice the difference :-)